# Getting error messages after setting allowBackup to false

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest

I am trying to disable backup in my app. When i add this following

```
<application
        android:name=".myAoo"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

It starts giving me this error message

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processArmeabi-v7aDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed with
>   multiple errors, see logs

What could be the reason of this error message, and why its only occurring when i am trying to disable `backup`.

Although `Manifest` file is giving multiple warnings like following.

> use $ instead of '.'

Comment: "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" -- when you looked at the Gradle Console output, what did it tell you?

Comment: Thanks That helped me, I didn;t know about the Gradle console output

Comment: Set like this 
  <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".CurrentLocationActivity">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open application manifest(AndroidManifest.xml) ,click on Merged Manifest.Check image
[image]

You can view error in right colum ,try to solve the error.It may help some one with same problem.